# How to call selenium webdriver tests contained in subdirectory in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am a newbie to Python, so please be patient with my ignorance here. Say, I have the following structure:

```
parentDir\
    runTests.py
    commonpageelements.py 
    testcases\
        __init__.py
        test1.py
        test2.py
```

I would like to initialize the webdriver and open the page in runTests.py, then pass parameters to test1.py, test2.py, etc.  For this example, I have a login test for test1.py.  I also would like to have a pageelements.py file that contains common page elements.  I will detail the python files below.

For commonpageelements.py I simply have the various elements defined like username="inspected_name".

I tried the following for runTests.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from testcases import *
import common_page_elements
import sys, unittest, re, time, os.path, logging

class RunTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.get("http://url_for_page")  

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

    def test_loginLogout(username, password):
        test_login_logout("myusername", "mypassword")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

Then, in test1.py I have:

```
class test1(username, password):

    def test_login_logout():
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_id(pageelements.textfield_username).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id(pageelements.textfield_username).send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_id(pageelements.textfield_password).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id(pageelements.textfield_password).send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_name(pageelements.button_submit).click()
        driver.find_element_by_id(pageelements.link_logout).click()
```

I'm just really not sure on how to achieve this.  I'm kind of flying blind here, attempting tweaks but getting nowhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Others will be able to add more value than I can, but a couple things I noticed:

- `if __name__ == '__main__'` needs to be on the outermost scope (otherwise it will stay inside the class and won't be executed).
- When you import `common_page_elements`, you don't reference it in `run_tests.py`. If that is where you are defining things like `username`, you need to explicitly reference `common_page_elements` in front of it.
- In your `test_loginLogout` function, you are passing two parameters to it. I'm not an expert, but I have never seen a situation where variables other than `self` are passed to a test case. Therefore even if you restructured your code to properly call the function `test_login_logout` from `test1.py`, you aren't passing `self` (which will hold the contents of `setUp`. Therefore this won't work.
- If you are going to run tests from different modules I *believe* that each module has to be hermetic with its test cases, meaning that they should be able to be run independently. In  your case, `test1.py` doesn't appear to have any of the information necessary to run the report you want with the setup you require.
- With the above point in mind, you may want to use the `unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule()` function, which will let you load other test modules and execute them.

This is completely untested (horrible pun, I know) code, but something like this may work in your situation:

```
import logging, os.path, re, sys, time, unittest
from testcases import test1, test2

def main():
    # Create a loader object
    test_loader = unittest.TestLoader()

    # Add your tests
    suite = test_loader.loadTestsFromModule(test1)
    suite.addTests(test_loader.loadTestsFromModule(test2))

    # Run the tests
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

As for the `setUp` and `tearDown` pieces, I would put those in your test modules themselves, so your `Test1Test` could look like this:

```
# test1.py

import common_page_elements as page_elements

from selenium import webdriver


class Test1Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.get("http://url_for_page")  

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

    def testLoginLogout(self):
        # Likely not necessary to redefine `driver` here - just use `self.driver`
        driver = self.driver
        # Not sure how this relates to the `get` in `setUp`
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_id(page_elements.textfield_username).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id(page_elements.textfield_username).send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_id(page_elements.textfield_password).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id(page_elements.textfield_password).send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_name(page_elements.button_submit).click()
        driver.find_element_by_id(pageelements.link_logout).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by rewriting the runTests.py as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from testcases import login
import common_page_elements
import sys, unittest, re, time, os.path, logging

class runTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()        
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://url_for_page"
        self.driver.get(self.base_url)

    def testLogin(self):
        test1.test_login(self, "myusername", "mypassword") 

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()


and test1.py as:

    import common_page_elements

    def test_login(self, username, password):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_id(common_page_elements.textfield_username).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id(common_page_elements.textfield_username).send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_id(common_page_elements.textfield_password).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id(common_page_elements.textfield_password).send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_name(common_page_elements.button_submit).click()
```

Comment: I added an answer that may be of some use. The main idea is that it will keep your tests better compartmentalized and easier to execute en masse. Hope it helps :)